# Move in velocity the UAV in attitude mode

Tags: dji-sdk

First of all I am sorry for my English.

I am trying to control the UAV with the DJI A3 in speed without GPS, indoors.

With no GPS, the drone flies in ATTITUDE mode. I am in P_GPS mode to obtain control authority. Due to not having GPS, the UAV is in ATTITUDE and although I have the authority control the UAV does not move.

Is there any possible way to move the UAV in speed while in ATTITUDE mode by not having GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You won't be able to use velocity or position control but you should be able to set roll, pitch and yaw angles on the control flags. Take a look at the following links here:

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/10

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/294

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/248